# The baby was sleeping or slept?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, past-continuous

I'm having a misunderstanding regarding Past Simple and Past Prog.

> The baby was sleeping peacefully through the night.

or

> The baby slept peacefully through the night.

Are both work? If not, what is the difference and how can I differentiate between those tenses regarding these types of questions?

Also, is it correct to say:

> She **has worn** short hair for two years.

it is a strange expression for me.

Comment: More usual variants would be *She has worn her hair short for two years.* or *She has been wearing her hair short for two years.*  Compare *He drinks his tea tepid.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are simply describing a single thing (the baby sleeping), then you would use

> The baby slept peacefully through the night.

However, if you are going on to say something happened **while** the baby was sleeping, then you would use the other

> The baby was sleeping peacefully through the night when her parents accidentally locked themselves out.

About your second question, it's perfectly grammatical (and doesn't sound crazy) to say

> She has worn short hair for two years.

Using "worn" to describe a hair style sounds a bit old (like 1950's old) to me and this isn't the most common way to say this.  If I had a friend in this situation, I would say

> She has had short hair for two years.

or possibly

> She has kept her hair short for two years.

Comment: With respect to "1950's old", there are plenty of post-2000 attestations. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22wears%20her%20hair%20short%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: I didn't say it isn't used any more (many people from the 1950s are still alive and speaking) but I believe it would be more rare for someone my age or younger would choose to say it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Both of the sentences about babies are correct, but they mean slightly different things. The former (... was sleeping...) suggests that something happened (or could have happened) and caused a change in the baby's state. Example:

> The baby *was sleeping peacefully* through the night until a thunderstorm woke her.

The latter sentence means that the baby did sleep peacefully through the entire night. No interruptions, no changes of state.

> The baby *slept peacefully* through the night. I guess the thunderstorm didn't bother her.